# How to create a textfield cell in primefaces datatable with action that do a computation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm currently working on a dynamic datatable. Let's say this table has 4 columns (name, x, y, z). x, y must be number text field and z is a label which shows the sum of x and y. When the values on either x or y is changed the value on z must be recomputed.

My problem right now is I'm not able to bind the text fields to the datatable entity, if I use the edit from primefaces, I need to add an edit event which I don't like. Also it display the cell initially as label, then need to click it to show the textfield.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Well if you follow the primefaces showcase for an editable datatable (cell) you just have to add an p:ajax change updating the data table, the Z column been a label with an el expression with the calculation like `#{varDT.x + varDT.y}` should solve your problem

Comment: hi Jorge, thanks for the comment but adding is not really my problem but more on the display. In primefaces edit datatable, we need a clickable label first as output, but I want a textfield for both input and output. Also the z variable is also a field in the model, because I need to save it in db.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve] and act accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution, instead of using primefaces datatable.edit feature. I just use a textfield in the cell and added a p:ajax that triggers a recompute method on change. Note the use of update parameter, we can directly reference a field on the row.

```
<h:form id="creditNoteLinesForm">
    <p:dataTable id="resultsId_creditNoteLines" var="entity"
        value="#{creditNoteBean.entity.creditNoteLines}">
        <!-- // -->
        <p:column
            headerText="#{messages['creditNote.list.amountWithoutTax']}">
            <p:inputText value="#{entity.amountWithoutTax}">
                <p:ajax event="change"
                    listener="#{creditNoteBean.reCompute(entity)}"
                    update="amountWithTax"></p:ajax>
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{messages['creditNote.list.amountTax']}">
            <p:inputText value="#{entity.taxAmount}">
                <p:ajax event="change"
                    listener="#{creditNoteBean.reCompute(entity)}"
                    update="amountWithTax"></p:ajax>
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column
            headerText="#{messages['creditNote.list.amountWithTax']}">
            <h:outputText id="amountWithTax" value="#{entity.amountWithTax}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

sdfdsf

```
public void reCompute(CreditNoteLine line) {
    line.computeWithTax();
}
```